# CouchDB sort doesn't work

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I recently started using CouchDB but I have no success with the sort-option using mango query.

My database is a simple person dataset and for this example I'd like to show all documents with the type "person" and sort it by the "firstName".

```
{
  "selector": {
    "type": "person"
  },
  "sort" : ["firstName"]
}
```

But it doesnt work. I just get the documents without any particular order.

[image]

This is the list of my indexes:

```
special: _id
json: gender
json: firstName
json: lastName
```

Is there something I forgot?

---

**Edit:**

As Alexis also pointed out, the docs say that the sorted field has to be present in the selector.

After testing around I figured out that the best way would be adding a greater than null condition to the field. That works in my case.

Comment: Your sort field must be in the selector I think

Comment: @AlexisCôté I figured that out, but it somehow works only if you check if the field ist $gt null. That's a bit strange, if i want to get all names Starting with e.g "P" and sort I have to add firstName $gt null, too.